# Docker container print to the docker ps status filed (health: starting)

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, status

I noticed that gitlab image container when starting adds additional info to the `status` field of the `docker ps` command:

> Up 19 seconds **(health: starting)**

once its got ready the status changed to:

> Up 3 minutes **(healthy)**

Usually there is no information in brackets present but gitlab somehow manages to print that additional text to the status field.

How to print an arbitrary text to the status field when running container? Should this be done inside the Dockerfile or the running container should have a process that outputs the text that appears in status field of docker ps?

to run gitlab you may use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e;
set -f;

export GITLAB_HOME="/tmp/gitlab/srv/gitlab";
mkdir -p "$GITLAB_HOME";
mkdir -p "$GITLAB_HOME/var/opt/gitlab";
mkdir -p "$GITLAB_HOME/var/log/gitlab";
mkdir -p "$GITLAB_HOME/etc/gitlab";

docker run --detach \
--publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
--name gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

after running it run

```
docker ps
```

to see the additional text in the status field, after approx 1min it should change to (healthy)

Comment: Pretty sure the text is from docker, not the process. If the healthcheck passes for a minute, docker prints healthy, the contained process doesn't set the string.

Comment: @zero298 That's what I thought initially but non of the other containers prints any additional information and MySQL when has its cold start can take even more time than gitlab but does not print any additional info

Comment: Confirming what @zero298 said; that is Docker printing the result of the `HEALTHCHECK` commands defined in the image.